# Singularity failing to create slave on Rancher with RHEL 7 instances

Tags: docker-compose, mesos, rancher

I'm trying to deploy [Singularity](https://github.com/HubSpot/Singularity) on Rancher with a set of RHEL 7.3 (3.10.0) instances. Everything else works fine but the slave node keeps failing to start giving the following error.

> Failed to create a containerizer: Could not create MesosContainerizer:
>   Failed to create launcher: Failed to create Linux launcher: Failed to
>   determine the hierarchy where the subsystem freezer is attached

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this sollution](https://github.com/eBayClassifiedsGroup/PanteraS/issues/142#issuecomment-159412609)

> try to use mesos-slave option `--launcher=posix`
>   you can permanently set it by echo `'MESOS_SLAVE_PARAMS="--launcher=posix"' >> restricted/host`
>   with new image you can also do it in mesos way: `echo MESOS_LAUNCHER=posix >> restricted/env`
>
> In case of Ubuntu (Debian), you can add this value to `/etc/default/mesos-slave`
>
> ```
> MESOS_LAUNCHER=posix
> ```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: It depends on how you run Mesos Agent. IMO just put env variable `MESOS_LAUNCHER=posix` into config file with other Mesos variables

Comment: Can I do this with the Singularity's docker-compos.yml file or I have to change the Dockers?

Comment: I think you can set this variable in `docker-compose.yml` but I'm not sure. I've never set up Mesos that way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer should work, but I still could not find where I should make this change. Can someone help me with this? :/